# Xamarin Studio & Xcode 5

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xcode5

I would like to test Xcode 5 without corrupting my Xamarin Studio/Xcode 4.6 environment.

I'm out of the office and can't backup my Mac right now. Has anybody tried this already? What steps do I need to follow?

Comment: If you have Xcode 5 at the time of this writing, you agreed not to discuss it publicly. Use Apple's developer forum instead.

Comment: We are discussing Xamarin and I can hardly do that in the Apple forums.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install multiple Xcodes in parallel and Xamarin Studio has an "SDK Settings" panel which allows you to point Xamarin Studio at the Xcode path of your choice. I think it may need a restart after changing it, but otherwise it should work assuming that Xcode 5 hasn't changed the overall directory structure.

I maintain the Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac (and MonoMac) addins for Xamarin Studio and will be installing Xcode 5 today to make sure things work and fix things if they don't.

Comment: Xamarin Studio found the SDK when I pointed it to the new Xcode5-DP.app.

Comment: Works perfectly (I'm still using Xamarin with 4.6 for now), thanks.

Comment: This worked but says it cant find the compiler, I have downloaded and installed command line tools on xcode 5, still no luck.